# Snowdrake is affecting my genocide run

Tags: undertale

I'm trying to do the genocide route in undertale, I'm at snowdrake but when I attack him it says [press Z] which I am doing, I have checked to make sure numerous times even though I know for a fact I'm pressing Z. No matter what I do it says that I'm missing, I know I can't do genocide without killing snowdrake, so what am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: with the tough glove you need to make sure you're "spamming" z. don't just hit it once, don't hit it once then once again after a few seconds just mash it. If that doesn't work, equip your stick/toy knife

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems like you are using the tough glove. After you hit Z to stop the line on the bar, you will need to press Z multiple times. You should need to press it at least 4 times and the faster you press it, the more damage you do. You can also of course, use a different weapon instead.